# Отправка формы на почту и в телеграм одновременно

Tags: telegram, email, форма

Всем привет. Имеется форма

```
<form action="sendmail.php" data-ajax="" method="POST" class="request__right" data-goto-error="" data-popup-message="#thanks">
                        <div class="request__inp-box">
                            <label for="name" class="request__inp-label">
                                Name
                            </label>
                            <input data-required="" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="name"  placeholder="" class="input">
                        </div>
                        <div class="request__inp-box">
                            <label for="surname" class="request__inp-label">
                                Surname
                            </label>
                            <input data-required="" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="" class="input">
                        </div>
                        <div class="request__inp-box">
                            <label for="phone" class="request__inp-label">
                                Phone
                            </label>
                            <input data-required="" autocomplete="off" type="tel" name="phone" class="input form-phone" inputmode="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="request__inp-box">
                            <label for="mail" class="request__inp-label">
                                E-mail
                            </label>
                            <input data-required="email" autocomplete="off" type="email" name="mail" placeholder="" class="input">
                        </div>                          
                        
                        <div class="request__btn-box">
                            <button type="submit" class="button">
                                Submit
                                <img src="img/sub-btn.svg" alt="">
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Хочу отправлять завяку и в тг, и на почту, но приходит только на почту. Может кто подсказать где ошибка?

```
<?php 

$token = "Тут мой токен";

$chat_id = "Тут мой айди";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setLanguage('ru', 'phpmailer/language/');
$mail->IsHTML(true);

    //От кого письмо
$mail->setFrom('info@denedsy.com', 'DenEdSy'); // Указать нужный E-mail
//Кому отправить
$mail->addAddress('votan14@gmail.com'); // Указать нужный E-mail
$mail->addAddress('denedsy.world@gmail.com'); // Указать нужный E-mail

//Тема письма
$mail->Subject = 'DenEdSy"';

//Тело письма
$body = '<h1>Заявка!</h1>';


    $txt = " ";
    if(trim(!empty($_POST['name']))){
        $body.='<p><strong>Name:</strong> '.$_POST['name'].'</p>';        
    }
    if(trim(!empty($_POST['surname']))){
        $body.='<p><strong>Surname:</strong> '.$_POST['surname'].'</p>';        
    }
    if(trim(!empty($_POST['phone']))){
        $body.='<p><strong>Phone:</strong> '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>';        
    }
    if(trim(!empty($_POST['mail']))){
        $body.='<p><strong>E-mail:</strong> '.$_POST['mail'].'</p>';        
    }
        


    $mail->Body = $body;
    
            // Массив с данными полученными из формы обратной связи
$arr = [
    "Name: " => trim(strip_tags($_POST['name'])),
    "Surname: " => trim(strip_tags($_POST['surname'])),
    "Телефон: " => trim(strip_tags($_POST['phone'])),
    "Email: " => trim(strip_tags($_POST['mail'])),
];

// Создаем строку со всеми данными от клиента для передачи API Telegram
  foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
    };
    
    
    //Отправляем
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $message = 'Error';
    } else {
        $message = 'Success!';
    $sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text='{$txt}'","r");
        
        
    }

    $response = ['message' => $message];

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```